# AttributeError: type object 'ParentClass' has no attribute '_ChildClass__init'

Tags: python-3.x, oop

```
class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1='Python'
        self.a2='Java'
        self.a3='C++'

    def printParent(self):
        print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(self.a1, self.a2, self.a3))


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
              ParentClass.__init(self)
              pass


child = ChildClass()
child.printParent()
```

When I run this code, it keeps saying that

> "AttributeError: type object 'ParentClass' has no attribute
>   '_ChildClass__init'"

I don't know why.

Comment: Is the method called `__init` or `__init__`?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're using:

```
ParentClass.__init(self)
```

where you likely meant to use:

```
ParentClass.__init__(self)
```

The code does work when you update it to use `ParentClass.__init__(self)`.